# How to loop and continue running script in same time (autohotkey)

Tags: loops, autohotkey, continue

I want to do a script in AHK, which loops for something, but continue running the script in a normal way.

Let's say that I have

loop
{
check if file exist every hour
}

msgbox, more code below
...

I want to make a script which checks every 1 hour if a file exists, but I don't want the script to be stuck on the loop function, I want to use the script as normal script, running from the beginning to the end, but keep the loop checking for the file.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: See [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).

Comment: Add the msgbox in the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (before the first return or hotkey), if you want to see it once when the script starts. After the first return you can add more stuff (hotkeys, hotstrings, functions, directives, labels etc.) to the script.